# View Mosek's License server status via URL

Tags: mosek

We are using Mosek's Floating License offering.

That means, the `Mosek's license server` runs on a separate dedicated server (=`xyz` and at a port=`abc`) on-premises. It displays the started the server is started at `127.0.0.1`.

Though we (as developer) can use terminal to `ssh` into that server `xyz` and check if `Mosek license server` is up and running.

But for others (non-developer) - its difficult to check Mosek's uptime since they cannot use terminal. (That is the pain-point)

Is it possible to check Mosek's uptime via browser? (possibly by visiting the URL: `https://127.0.0.1:abc` - this doesn't work for some reason).

(Note: This isn't a necessity but good to have feature for us)

Comment: In Python you could try to make a socket connection to the relevant host:port. If it succeeds you can reasonably assume that it's up and running

Comment: Hi Arthur, I had tried `https://xyz:abc` but it doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be a support request to the vendor of that product. [We can't answer customer service questions here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/354577).

Comment: @pqrz That is presumably because there's no HTTP(S) server on that host:port. Check your Mosek documentation for options

Comment: Does Mosek use `flexlm` to manage license?

Comment: Yes, it indeed uses the `flexlm` license manager

Comment: ``lmutil lmstat -c host@port -a`` like here: https://docs.mosek.com/latest/licensing/floating-license.html#id1 gives current status and can be called from remote also

Comment: If something is possible with FlexLM it will be described in http://docs.mosek.com/generic/fnp_LicAdmin.pdf I don't think there is any protocol allowing that through HTTP. Only my previous comment.

Comment: Hi Michal, We are aware of `lmutil`. Very thanks for the confirmation on `HTTP(S)` though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flask`:

Create the script `flexlm.py`

```
# pip install flask
from flask import Flask, Response
import subprocess

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/status")
def status():
    run = subprocess.run(['/opt/flexlm/lmutil', 'lmstat', '-a'], capture_output=True)
    return Response(run.stdout, mimetype='text/plain')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

Note: you have to customize the parameters of `subprocess.run`

Run `flask` application server:

```
[...]$ python3 flexlm.py
 * Serving Flask app 'flexlm' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on all addresses.
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
 * Running on http://10.202.120.7:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
10.202.241.181 - - [01/Mar/2022 14:38:04] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
10.202.241.181 - - [01/Mar/2022 14:38:08] "GET /status HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Go to http://xyz:5000/status